# How to return Mongo's _id with session in NextAuth?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I'm new to NextAuth. I'm using the NextAuth credentials provider with Mongodb.
Based on NextAuth documentation, if I want to check the user session I could use useSession() in client components while getServerSession() for server components. By default, the session contains a user object which contains only name, email, and image properties. But what if I want to pass additional properties to my session like the _id that Mongodb generates when creating documents?

According to NextAuth, If I want to pass additional data to the session, I should add an acync callback session to my auth options. Since I'm using a JWT strategy which is the default strategy, I should add an async jwt callback before the session callback.

My auth options:

```
export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Sign in',
            credentials: {},
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                const { email, password } = credentials

                try {
                    await connectDB()
                    const customer = await Customer.findOne({ email })
                    if (!customer) null

                    //check whether the passwords are correct
                    const pwdComparisonResult = await bcrypt.compare(password, customer.password)
                    if (pwdComparisonResult) {
                        return customer
                    }

                    return null

                } catch (error) {
                    console.log('error ', error);
                }
            }
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt(token, user, session) {
            //What I should write and return inside jwt?
        },

        async session({ session, token, user }) {
            //What I should write and return inside session?
        }
    },
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt"
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login',
    }
}
```

As far as I know, the jwt will return a token and the session callback will receive this token and return a session. Is that true? Could someone explain how data flows between the authorize, jwt, and session and what logic I should be writing in the jwt and session callbacks in order to be able to access the mongo id along with the name and email properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `authorize` callback receives the `credentials` and `req` parameters. The credentials parameter contains information obtained during the authentication process.

```
 // Callbacks are asynchronous functions you can use to control what happens when an action is performed.
  callbacks: {
    //   jwt callback is only called when token is created
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      // user is obj that we have received from authorize. in your case it is customer
      user && (token.user = user);
      // it should be Promise.resolve(token) otherwise you may get some error
      return Promise.resolve(token);
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      // session callback is called whenever a session for that particular user is checked
      //   console.log("user in ...next auth api", token);
      // we can add more properties here to the session obj
      session.user = token.user;
      console.log("session", session);
      // since I get error, I return Promise.resolve(session)
      return Promise.resolve(session);
    },
```

Comment: Is the following true? The user object that is returned by the authorize function on successful login will be passed to the jwt callback along with the newly created token. The jwt is called when the token is created and when the authorize returns a user object. Then jwt passes the returned token to the session which returns at the end the session.  The session callback is called first on login and when useSession or getServerSession is used.

Comment: True! You can console.log each object that passed to callbacks and examine it